# Проблемы с DexClassLoader-ом

Tags: android, genymotion, java

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь научиться исполнять загруженные jar и apk файлы с помощью DexClassLoader.
Вот нашел в Сети код:

```
String defaultLibPath =  mActivity.getAssets() + "/Plugins/HelloWorld.jar";
File dexOutputDir = mActivity.getDir("dex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
DexClassLoader dcl = new DexClassLoader(defaultLibPath,
   dexOutputDir.getAbsolutePath(),
   null,
   ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
try{
   Class<?> clazz = dcl.loadClass("HelloWorld");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Залил в эмулятор Genymotion свой jar-файл: HelloWorld.jar. Вот его исходник:

```
package pack;

public class HelloWorld {

    static int summer(int a, int b){
        int c = a+b;
        System.out.print( "Summ is \n" + c ); 
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int c = summer(5, 6);
    }
}
```

По коду из Сети:

Пусть путь к исполняемому файлу хранится здесь: `String defaultLibPath`.  Нечто, что будет исполняться, будет находиться здесь: `dexOutputDir`. Доступ к исполняемому файлу получу через dcl. А вот тут непосредственно имеем класс, который загрузили: `Class<?> clazz = dcl.loadClass("HelloWorld");`.  Это тот самый класс, который пришел по сети и будет исполняться. Вышеприведенные рассуждения верны?

Вот проблема: AndroidStudio в режиме отладки выдает:

```
dcl = "dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[/mnt/sdcard/MyFiles/HelloWorld.jar]"

Exception:
e = "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld"
```

Что не так? Говорит, на сколько я понимаю, что не нашел класс HelloWorld. В чем может быть причина? В сети по этой теме куча всего навалено, но мне особо это не помогло. Заранее благодарен за ответы. )

**Обновление**

Выяснил, что чтобы запустить Jar на андроиде, его нужно конвертировать в "dalvik".

Тут полезные статьи по теме конвертации:

1. http://normandocarvalho.com/2013/08/17/how-to-convert-external-jar-that-contains-java-bytecode-to-dalvik-bytecode/
2. http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/command-line-java-on-dalvikvm/
3. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Т.к. я не спец по андроиду, по этому никак не могу понять, как преобразовать Jar в dex.

В эклипсе создаю проект `Helloworld->Export->Runnable Jar`. Затем не знаю, как быть дальше. Пытался прописать:

> "K:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\"dx --dex --output=classes.dex HelloWorld2.jar

Выкидывает ошибки.

Comment: лучшею юзай genymotion

Comment: Вот только что пришел к этому... А насчет DexClassLoader мои рассуждеения верны? Может, я не совсем верно понял, как это работает?

Answer (score 0):

Просто создай бандл из проекта(с HelloWorld классом) и из него вытянешь classes.dex для загрузки через DexClassLoader. Build -> Build bundles потом идёшь в папку необходимого модуля, дальше в папку build -> outputs -> bundles -> файл открываешь архиватором и ищещь classes.dex